# How do I connect a line to a graph of the graph?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to connect a line of plot to plot which describe about plot's name, in the following code:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Any suggestion?

[image: plot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Plot[{Callout[Sin[x], "sin(x)", Above], Callout[Cos[x], "cos(x)", Above]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Callout` as the option setting for `PlotLabels`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabels -> Callout["Expressions", Above]]
```

[image]